# Showing access error for user group in my custom module in odoo

Tags: security, odoo-8

I have created a custom module. In my module two user groups are there, i.e Admin  and user. Administrator can able to save records. When user is logged in and trying to save record, it is giving access error. But i have added access right for every model for user. Even though it is showing access error.

Answer (score 1):

I agree you add access rights,but may somewhere else this user haven't rights of other object, so in that case user also can not save because of access rights.

can you show me in image or in more detail?